# Vue frontend sends to identical requests to Phalcon backend each time, and the second one fails, so the request fails

Tags: api, vue.js, phalcon

I'm working on this website. I have signed an NDA so I can't post any code, but I can explain what's going on and post what's going on in the PHP terminal. There's a Vue frontend, there's a Phalcon backend. The Vue frontend is configured with the Phalcon backend, The frontend is running on Webpack, and Phalcon is running on php7.2. I'm on Debian Stretch. But it's showing some odd behavior. It sends two requests milliseconds apart. The first one sends back 200 and succeeds, but the second one sends back 404 and fails, thus the whole operation fails. The same thing happens if I open some of the API routes in Postman, it says "Controller Class Not Found". But, for example, an IndexController action opens up fine. Let's just see the console.

```
[Fri Apr 19 10:13:45 2019] ::1:58106 [404]: /
[Fri Apr 19 10:14:00 2019] ::1:58110 [200]: /api/v1/users
[Fri Apr 19 10:22:42 2019] ::1:58146 [200]: //api/v1/displays?limit=all&include=team
[Fri Apr 19 10:22:47 2019] ::1:58148 [404]: //api/v1/displays?limit=all&include=team
[Fri Apr 19 11:18:03 2019] ::1:58534 [200]: //api/auth/register
[Fri Apr 19 11:18:03 2019] ::1:58532 [404]: //api/auth/register
[Fri Apr 19 12:04:05 2019] ::1:58552 [200]: //api/auth/register
[Fri Apr 19 12:04:05 2019] ::1:58550 [404]: //api/auth/register
[Fri Apr 19 12:11:50 2019] ::1:58680 [200]: //api/auth/register
[Fri Apr 19 12:11:50 2019] ::1:58682 [404]: //api/auth/register
```

The Vue is the stable branch, but the API is the development branch, however, I've been told it works.

Comment: Looks like a CORs issue

Comment: @DerekPollard Well this is the first time I'm hearing this term... I'm running all this on a localhost. I googled my issue + CORS and not so many results showed up. Can you give me the ballpark of what I'm in for?

Comment: It's a relatively easy fix, you just need to add the proper headers to the phalcon application response so vue can access the API

Comment: if you look in the developer console, the vue app should be sending an `OPTIONS` request before each actual request

Comment: @DerekPollard The API uses JWTs to handle requests. The API key and and the Vue key are the same. However, Vue says it can't find the controller. What could the reason be?

Comment: @DerekPollard How can I see what's happening behind npm run dev? I tried --verbose and it didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192119/discussion-between-major-despard-and-derek-pollard).